# How to have entire item in Qualtrics remain in position when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, qualtrics

I am presenting an image embedded in a descriptive text item, followed by several questions about that image. I would like that item to remain in place while the participant scrolls.

I've been able to get the entire image to remain in place using something like this HTML code:

```
<html>
<style>

.image{position: fixed; background: white;}

</style>

<div class = "image">
<img src="LOCATION OF IMAGE FILE" style="width: 395px; height: 395px;" />
</div>
</html>
```

But this freezes the image itself in a very awkward place (it actually does this in the editor itself, which blocks me from doing anything else). Is there a way to keep the presentation of the item exactly the same as it is normally, but just keep it in place?

Edit:
[This is how it should appear, as a separate item from the questions to follow. I would then like it to remain frozen in place while the user can scroll through the questions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhOfQ.png)

[This shows how it currently appears. The image is frozen in place, but not where it should appear (i.e., above and separated from the questions that follow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvQ4U.png)

---

Comment: Can you share a Screenshot of the issue and expectation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a spacer element to align the starting height of other elements. For example:

```
<div class = "image">
    <img src="LOCATION OF IMAGE FILE" width="395px" height="395px"/>
</div>

<div class = "image_spacer">
    This is a spacer element
</div>

<style>
    .image{
        position: fixed; 
        background: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .image_spacer{
        height: 395px; 
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Visually speaking, I may recommend adding a width of 100% to your image div as well, so that other elements are fully covered when you scroll.

To fix at the top on scroll, do the following:

```
<div class = "image">
    <img src="IMAGE LOCATION HERE" width="395px" height="395px"/>
</div>

<div class = "image_spacer">
    This is a spacer element
</div>

<style>
    .image{
        background: white;
        width:100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .image.fixed{
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    .image_spacer{
        height: 395px; 
        visibility: hidden;
        display:none;
    }
    .image_spacer.fixed{
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```

In addition, add this to the JavaScript for the question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var space = $$('.image')[0].cumulativeOffset().top;
console.log(space);
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if( document.body.scrollTop >  space){
            $$('.image')[0].addClassName('fixed');
            $$('.image_spacer')[0].addClassName('fixed');
    }
    else{
            $$('.image')[0].removeClassName('fixed');
            $$('.image_spacer')[0].removeClassName('fixed');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly!

One quick question: I don't seem to be able to center the image any longer. I've tried <div style="text-align:center"> and it doesn't seem to work. Is it a result of the code? If so, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Shoot, I'm also just realizing that once the questions get scrolled to a certain point, they are visible above the image. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You should be able to align center, I'll look in to it. The solution to  your other question is to let the image pin to the top of the screen. However if your survey has a  once the header has been scrolled past. I have  updated the post with a solution to this using some JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm thanks again for getting back to me. This did center the image, but (after removing the "//" before the first position:fixed; I assumed this was a typo?), I have the old issue of the questions appearing above the image after scrolling.

Comment: The position fixed should be removed from the image class. It is added on scroll when the fixed class is added using JS. It centers fine with that line removed.

Comment: Ah! I think it may have been a browser issue! This latest example works perfectly in Safari, but not Google Chrome. I will just use Safari for the survey. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Dave, interesting... the example I shared seems to work fine in chrome, edge, and Firefox...

Comment: Must be something to do with my particular settings. That's okay, it won't be an issue to use Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Text/Graphic option?
[image]

As I am seeing no problem if I add an image that way, and the survey questions are in their place, check the image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: My issue is that I would like the image to be frozen in place when scrolling (i.e., would like the image to always remain where it is, while the questions scroll). Are you able to help do that with the Text/Graphic option?

Comment: I tried including the same in the Header part, but the image is being displayed in the background. I am not sure if this can be achieved, anyways good luck. Please do post your answer if you get it work. Thanks