# Freeze image at top of a Qualtrics block

Tags: javascript, html, image, survey, qualtrics

I'm trying to freeze an image at the top of a Qualtrics survey block.

Participants will answer questions based on the image, so it will need to stay anchored to the top of the screen in view while they scroll down to answer several questions.

I'm trying to use the code [Anthony Rivas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3869738/anthony-rivas) kindly provided in this post to do this:

[How to have entire item in Qualtrics remain in position when scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286498/how-to-have-entire-item-in-qualtrics-remain-in-position-when-scrolling)

```html
<div class = "image">
    <img src="IMAGE LOCATION HERE" width="395px" height="395px"/>
</div>

<div class = "image_spacer">
    This is a spacer element
</div>

<style>
    .image{
        background: white;
        width:100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .image.fixed{
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    .image_spacer{
        height: 395px; 
        visibility: hidden;
        display:none;
    }
    .image_spacer.fixed{
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```

I've added the image using this html in a text-based question, and added the corresponding JS. But it's not working for me: the image is still scrolling with everything else.

What's frustrating is that this has worked for me previously on another survey! Is it possible that Qualtrics might have changed something and now this code needs an update? (I'm not familiar with html or JS so this is beyond me to troubleshoot.)

UPDATE: I've replaced Anthony's JS with that shown [here](https://www.qualtrics.com/community/discussion/1622/keeping-an-image-frozen-in-place-when-scrolling-issue-with-spacer-element-in-javascript-html)

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
 
$$('.image').forEach(ele=>ele.addClassName('fixed'));
 
});
```

...and now the block image is frozen at the top BUT Question 1 is hidden behind it.

[image: See image of this here]